# Modification of how the data is controlled/showed and stored

Tags: custom-post-types, table

**Before you read:**
The ticket is just an example we don’t want an actual plugin for that. It is just to visualize the issue.

Ticket can be a support ticket, invoice, sale etc. Just like `wp_post` has “custom post type”.

Why we choose to store in a custom table: TL;TR but this is an optimization and scalability->integration. So the custom table is necessary.

**User Story:**
We have a custom table that store some data about tickets and another one to store some `meta data`(like the default wp_postmeta).
Now we want to have a user visit a page and populate the data from the `wp_tickets` and `wp_ticketmeta` table in a similar to how the user see a post page.

**My question** isn’t the query itself but how I should approach this scenario where we have a custom table(s) which store data that we want users to be able to see. This date can be **public** available like `www.example.com/create-a-ticket` and also **private** like `www.example.com/ticket-id-12344` (403 if not authenticated).

My first approach is to have a `wp_post` entry and map this id to my `wp_tickets` table. When a user navigates to the post I would query the wp_tickets and wp_ticketmeta to populate the template(twig).

Do you have any other approach?